# Character limit when submitting a custom Open Graph story for review

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Since Facebook upgraded the developer site design I've come across a strange issue where the 'Review Instructions' only allow 256 characters when submitting a custom open graph story for review, which isn't anywhere near enough space for detailed instructions. The validation message I get is:

"Length of param review instructions must be less than or equal to 256"

Am I expected to write detailed instructions within such a small limit? I've not had this issue with previous custom stories (though they were submitted using the old developers site).

Thanks,
Matt